# Error using Elasticsearch Java Client from Websphere

Tags: java, elasticsearch, websphere, elasticsearch-java-api

I have a web application that uses the elasticsearch official java client. When using that web application on Websphere 8.5.5 using IBM JVM Java 7, I get the error below. I tried using Transport Client and Node Client. Also tried using Oracle JavaSE 7 and 8 as the JVM for Elasticsearch. But nothing worked out.
Elasticsearch does not run on IBM JVM and Websphere only runs on IBM JVM.

Does anyone know a way to use the elasticsearch official java client from an application on Websphere?

Below is the error stack trace:

```
Caused by: org.elasticsearch.transport.TransportSerializationException: Failed to deserialize exception response from stream
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:178)
at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.messageReceived(MessageChannelHandler.java:130)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$DefaultChannelHandlerContext.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:791)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:296)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.unfoldAndFireMessageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:462)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.callDecode(FrameDecoder.java:443)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.handler.codec.frame.FrameDecoder.messageReceived(FrameDecoder.java:303)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.handleUpstream(SimpleChannelUpstreamHandler.java:70)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:564)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.sendUpstream(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:559)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:268)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.Channels.fireMessageReceived(Channels.java:255)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.read(NioWorker.java:88)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.process(AbstractNioWorker.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioSelector.run(AbstractNioSelector.java:337)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.AbstractNioWorker.run(AbstractNioWorker.java:89)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioWorker.run(NioWorker.java:178)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.ThreadRenamingRunnable.run(ThreadRenamingRunnable.java:108)
at org.elasticsearch.common.netty.util.internal.DeadLockProofWorker$1.run(DeadLockProofWorker.java:42)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1156)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:626)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:780)
Caused by: java.io.StreamCorruptedException: unexpected end of block data
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1438)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.access$400(ObjectInputStream.java:217)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream$GetFieldImpl.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2201)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:603)
    at java.net.InetSocketAddress.readObject(InetSocketAddress.java:293)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:88)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:613)
    at java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1076)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1941)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1846)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2039)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1846)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.defaultReadFields(ObjectInputStream.java:2039)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:1963)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:1846)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1416)
    at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:419)
    at org.elasticsearch.transport.netty.MessageChannelHandler.handlerResponseError(MessageChannelHandler.java:176)
    ... 23 more
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only workaround to this problem is to use the same JVM for both Java applications. Serialization of Java exceptions can be inconsistent between the *same* JVM using different update versions, and clearly it's a problem between IBM's JVM and the one that you are running with Elasticsearch.

Specifically, Elasticsearch does not run on the IBM JVM because the [IBM JVM has bugs in it that prevent it from working correctly](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/need-help-with-ibm-jdk-issues-with-es-1-4-5/1748/3?u=pickypg).

Fortunately the outlook is getting *much* better here. [IBM is working with Elasticsearch to get it working properly](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/need-help-with-ibm-jdk-issues-with-es-1-4-5/1748/5?u=pickypg) *and* [Elasticsearch is removing serialization in Elasticsearch 2.0](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/pull/11910).